# How do I break out of a readline() loop in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

If "my friend" made the foolish mistake of entering the following code in RStudio, how would I (I mean, he!) break out of the loop (without restarting R)?

```
while (TRUE) readline()
```

Comment: Change the code to work correctly :)

Comment: well isn't this a predicament!

Comment: Changed the title to 'in RStudio' since other interfaces let you easily escape (including at least the Windows RGui and the Emacs ESS console -- a front-end for Rterm, IIUC -- also on Windows).

Comment: @JoshO'Brien thanks. My friend says it's also not a problem in Rterm on linux.

Comment: Usually I would click the stop symbol in the console panel.

Comment: as commented in linked/dupe question, also not an issue on MacOS running in terminal ... @VerenaHaunschmid, Stop symbol does not appear in this case.

Comment: Yes when looping with readline inside you can not interrupt by clicking the small red button, but you can type Esc to end the session.

Answer (score 4):

You can restart the R session within RStudio using: `Ctrl+Shift+F10` in Windows or `Command+Shift+F10` in Mac. The workspace and the command history won't be cleared so, I suppose, it would be as if you broke out of the loop.

Comment: I don't know if there's a difference in Linux, but this command does clear both.

Comment: In windows I've tried to do that but it doesn't work. It appears "Restarting R..." on the top and it remain in that state. Clicking on the stop red symbol on the panel works (not always).

Answer (score 1):

Using Esc could quit the command, while someone already wrote it in comment.